# Using ST_Buffer on a geometry in SRID 3035 changes location

Tags: qgis, postgis

I'm trying to buffer a linestring using PostGIS and get very strange results. Using this SQL in QGIS:

```
SELECT row_number() over () AS id, * FROM (SELECT st_asewkt(ST_Buffer(geometrie,20)) AS geometrie FROM "erhaltung"."abschnitt" )
  AS _subq_1_
```

on a table that has a "geometrie" column storing a LineString in SRID 3035, the resulting buffer is not where the linestring is located (some place in Germany), but in Saudi Arabia. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Comment: Hi, maybe you should check the projection afterwards, try Set_Srid(3035) in your process. Looks like projection issue.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly you have the axes order incorrect.

[EPSG:3035](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3035) is a projected CRS with axes in **Northing/Easting** order

```
PROJCRS["ETRS89 / LAEA Europe",
  BASEGEODCRS["ETRS89",
    DATUM["European Terrestrial Reference System 1989",
      ELLIPSOID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]]],
  CONVERSION["Europe Equal Area 2001",
    METHOD["Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area",ID["EPSG",9820]],
    PARAMETER["Latitude of natural origin",52,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252]],
    PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",10,ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252]],
    PARAMETER["False easting",4321000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]],
    PARAMETER["False northing",3210000,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
  CS[cartesian,2],
    AXIS["northing (Y)",north,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["easting (X)",east,ORDER[2]],
    LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0],
  ID["EPSG",3035]]
```

Comment: Would the data then show up correctly before doing the buffer? Before the buffer, they match perfectly with e.g. OpenStreetMap background images, and even after the buffer with the wrong location, general east/west/north/south orientation is correct.

Comment: Axis order is not the issue, when I flip the axis order using ST_FlipCoordinates, the location is still wrong, and then also the orientation.